# How to get the data of 10-10 row as a single row through SQL query among large set of data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that consist of multiple data of same ID with different-different time stamp(each interval of 6 minutes) in one column, and its recorded temperature at each given time stamp.

| ID | Time_Stamp | Temperature_1 | Temperature_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:05:40 | 98.50 | 87.63 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:11:40 | 96.60 | 46.3 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:17:40 | 80.50 | 65.30 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:23:40 | 65.30 | 77.21 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:29:40 | 36.20 | 63.30 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:35:40 | 69.30 | 54.70 |

..... up to 614 rows

Output should be:

| ID | Time_Stamp | Avg_Temperature_1 | Avg_Temperature_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 17:29:40 | 98.50 | 87.63 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 18:29:40 | 96.60 | 46.3 |
| 101 | 18-09-2020 19:29:40 | 80.50 | 65.30 |

..... up to 61 rows

Elaboration:

Lets assume it has 614 rows.
i have to first search all the data in ascending manner(by time_stamp) (e.g `select * from table where id=101 order by time_stamp asc`).

Now, I have 614 row of that data.but I have to consider only nearest 10 data. e.g if here 614 rows then i have to consider only 610 data. similarly if i will have 219 data, then i have to consider only 210 data (if 220 then i have to consider 220 data), if 155 then 150, if 314 then 310 data and so on..

so after considering 610 row i have to divide it by 10. so that in my final o/p i will have only 61 rows .(each of 10-10 set)
Also note that if i am taking 10-10 set then i will have each row showing avg of each hour in my final o/p)

how? (the data has came at interval of every 6-6 minute, so if i take 10 data together then it will have data of each 1-1 hour(6*10=60 min) representing by each row).

so finally i have to take set of 10-10 row and find the average of each temp column and represent it as a single row.
Note that in time_stamp column we can take any mid value of 10 set,either 4th one,5th one or 6th one.
And in Temp1 column it should be avg of 10 row.

i have to show the avg temp data of each 1-1 hour interval time or for 10-10 set of rows.

How to write a SQL query for this?

What I tried so far is as below - for this I thought to write a stored procedure:

- Step 1:- starting i will fetch all data and floor(cound(id)) value
  by:-

  ```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY Time_Stamp ASC
  ```

  and then

  ```
    SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(id) / 10) FROM table_name WHERE id = 1 (for deciding num of time loop should execute)
  ```

  This will return a value of 61.
- Step 2: looping on upto n times (here 61 times)

  And within each loop I suppose limit up to 10 rows and take avg of temperature and all.

  In each loop: finding the avg of column w.r.t id (but I am unable to include time stamp)

I use below for finding the avg with respect to id of first 10 data by:-

```
select id, avg(Temperature_1) as TempAVG1, avg(Temperature_2) as TempAVG2
from table_name
where Time_stamp >= TO_CHAR('18-09-2020 17:05')  
  and Time_stamp <= TO_CHAR('18-09-2020 18:05:40') 
  and id = 101 
group by id
```

Here I'm unable to include the time stamp (4, 5 or 6th one of 10 set)

So for that I tried to write another query for finding only time stamp and willing to do union with first query, but I am unable to union both query because avg column and time column have diff data types (also all columns are not same)

Also I cannot think how to left last odd rows ( e.g if lastly if there is only1 to 9 rows left)

Please provide another efficient way if possible to write query for this or try to help me to write this stored procedure.

Or else if it is/can be mixing of query and C# code (e.g., using datatable and all) then also its welcome.

Technologies I am using: C# and an Oracle database

Comment: Oracle <> MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: To_char() is an oracle function

Comment: Please, correct your tags. From [Oracle's tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) description: *Oracle Database is a Multi-Model Database Management System created by Oracle Corporation. Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL*

Comment: learn SQL Pattern matching. See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html#GUID-136DAC89-DA17-45C6-9E37-C9892723AC79

Comment: Thnks all of you

Comment: rather doing it through sql directly, i achieved the solution through c# code... (that included datatable,loop etc)...